# python selenium How do I choose the last message in the chat

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I use a library python selenium .
I want to click on the last message that appears in the chat.

this is website : https://i.bc.game/i-x40k2jw-n/

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("javascript.enabled")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
#options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://i.bc.game/i-x40k2jw-n/")
time.sleep(10)

while True:
    try:

        python_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".coindrop-status")
        python_button.click()

    except:
        print("wait...")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a lot easier if you had just pasted in the HTML.

But you could find all elements, and them grab the last one, and click on that element.

For example:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('coindrop-status')
last_element = elements[-1]
last_element.click()
```

In this example *elements* is a list holding all elements with the class name *coindrop-status*.
We then grab the last element, and click on it.

In your example you're also catching on all exceptions, while you want to except NoSuchElementException, when the element you are looking for isn't present.